# While Installing Mysql.msi through powershell getting below error

Tags: mysql, powershell

Am using below code:

```
$argumentList = @(
    'ACTION=Install'
    '/q'
    'INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files"'
    'SERVERTYPE =Full'
    'DATABASETYPE =Mixed'
    'CONNECTIONUSAGE=DSS'
    'PORT = 3306'
    'ServiceName=MySQL'
    'RootPassword=fakepassword123'
    'IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True' 
)
Start-Process -FilePath 'E:\mysql-installer-community-5.5.62.0.msi' -ArgumentList $argumentList -Wait
```

Error:

> Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.10240.16386
>
> msiexec /Option  [Optional Parameter]

```
Install Options
    </package | /i> <Product.msi>
        Installs or configures a product
    /a <Product.msi>
        Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
    /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
        Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
    </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Uninstalls the product
Display Options
    /quiet
        Quiet mode, no user interaction
    /passive
        Unattended mode - progress bar only
    /q[n|b|r|f]
        Sets user interface level
        n - No UI
        b - Basic UI
        r - Reduced UI
        f - Full UI (default)
    /help
        Help information
Restart Options
    /norestart
        Do not restart after the installation is complete
    /promptrestart
        Prompts the user for restart if necessary
    /forcerestart
        Always restart the computer after installation
Logging Options
    /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] <LogFile>
        i - Status messages
        w - Nonfatal warnings
        e - All error messages
        a - Start up of actions
        r - Action-specific records
        u - User requests
        c - Initial UI parameters
        m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
        o - Out-of-disk-space messages
        p - Terminal properties
        v - Verbose output
        x - Extra debugging information
        + - Append to existing log file
        ! - Flush each line to the log
        * - Log all information, except for v and x options
    /log <LogFile>
        Equivalent of /l* <LogFile>
Update Options
    /update <Update1.msp>[;Update2.msp]
        Applies update(s)
    /uninstall <PatchCodeGuid>[;Update2.msp] /package <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Remove update(s) for a product
Repair Options
    /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Repairs a product
        p - only if file is missing
        o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
        e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
        d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
        c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value
        a - forces all files to be reinstalled
        u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
        m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
        s - all existing shortcuts (default)
        v - runs from source and recaches local package
Setting Public Properties
    [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]
```

> Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the
>   command line syntax.
>
> Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call for `Start-Process` with `msiexec.exe` as file name and add the actual MSI file path to the list of the arguments using `/i` switch.
Using the code you provided, it would look like:

```
$argumentList = @(
    'ACTION=Install'
    '/q'
    '/i "E:\mysql-installer-community-5.5.62.0.msi"',   
    'INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files"'
    'SERVERTYPE =Full'
    'DATABASETYPE =Mixed'
    'CONNECTIONUSAGE=DSS'
    'PORT = 3306'
    'ServiceName=MySQL'
    'RootPassword=fakepassword123'
    'IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True' 
)

Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $argumentList -Wait
```

BTW: Avoid posting real passwords to SO questions.