# Install MySQL on Windows Docker Image

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, installation, containers

Anyone had success adding MySQL to a Windows docker image? I tried two different ways of deploying MySQL to my image.

I tried using the msi from MySQL in non-interactive mode. Does not work at all in a container.

[While Installing Mysql.msi through powershell getting below error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290069/while-installing-mysql-msi-through-powershell-getting-below-error)

I tried extracting the zip  to set things up manually using the mysqld commands does nothing at all. Literally nothing, the exectutables behave as if they just run and exit (no output, nothing):

https://github.com/Somesh-K/Automation-Mysql/blob/main/1.mysql_setup_v2.ps1

Something is very weird about all of this.

Yes, I know that there's a perfectly good MySQL docker linux container published by Oracle to Docker hub. This works. The problem is that running a Windows container and Linux container that need to interact creates a really unnecessary frustration for the user in terms of networking between the two.

Using a different back-end (like SQL server) for our application is not feasible and using .NET core instead of .NET framework is not feasible.  To simplify, I'd like to just install MySQL on our windows based webserver docker image. This seems do-able using the two methods described in the links above, but as noted, it does not work and there's very odd behavior from the MySQL binaries when they are run in the container.

Here's an example of the odd behavior:

**Install Docker Desktop for Windows**

**Download the Win32 install zips from MySQL and place in C:\mydata**

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

**Pull down the ASPNET image from Docker Hub, Run it, and Open up Powershell:**

```
# docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 
# docker run --name testweb -v C:\mydata:C:\mydata:R -d mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
# docker exec -it testweb powershell
C:\ > cd C:\mydata
C:\mydata\ > Expand-archive -path .\mysql-5.7.36-winx64.zip .
C:\mydata\ > cd \mysql-5.7.36-winx64\bin
C:\mydata\mysql-5.7.36-winx64\bin\ > .\mysql.exe -version
[zero output, acts like it's an empty executable]
```

**Results**

None of the executables/binaries in the extracted mysql bin directory on the container do anything at all.  They behave as if someone wrote and executable that just exits.  I thought I had a bad install zip so I extracted the same zip on my regular Windows 10 workstation. All of the binaries at least return errors or do something.

This is super odd.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Downloading this executable and putting it into my container seemed to do the trick:**

https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe

**Placed this on my container and started it**

```
C:\vcredist.exe /Q
```

**After doing this, the executables starting working:**

```
C:\ > cmd.exe /C "C:\mysql\bin\mysqld" --initialize-insecure
C:\ > cmd.exe /C "C:\mysql\bin\mysqld" --install

C:\ > start-service mysql
C:\ > cmd.exe /C "C:\mysql\bin\mysql" -u root
```

Comment: Had the same issue, thank you for the suggestion Brian. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Running a Dependency Walker on the mysqld binary shows that it still can't find the redistributable dll's. Not sure why. Ended up copying msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll to the mysql/bin directory. I'm not happy with this workaround but it appears to be working now..